# How to query using left join to get the result

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on two tables on mysql in which I am trying to get all rows from left table along with the columns in the second table which are matching with first table.

**business**

```
id | business_name
-------------------
1   |abc    
2   |def    
3   |ghi    
4   |jkl    
5   |mno
```

**orders**

```
business_id_fk  | order_status  | date 
----------------------------------------    
2               |  PCK         |  30-03-2017    
3               |  DEL         |  30-03-2017    
2               |  DEL         |  30-03-2017    
2               |  PCK         |  30-03-2017    
4               |  PCK         |  28-03-2017    
3               |  PCK         |  29-03-2017    
4               |  DEL         |  30-03-2017
```

I want all rows from business table and count of each order status for every business on 30-03-2017 from orders table sort by total.
result set is:

```
id | business_name | total(order_status) | count(PCK) | count(DEL) 
----------------------------------------------------
2  | def           | 3       | 2      |  1   
3  | ghi           | 1       | 0      |  1    
4  | jkl           | 1       | 0      |  1    
1  | abc           | 0       | 0      |  0    
5  | mno           | 0       | 0      |  0
```

Please help me in query to getting the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation on the join:

```
select b.id,
    b.business_name,
    count(o.order_status) as total_count,
    coalesce(sum(o.order_status = 'PCK'), 0) as count_PCK,
    coalesce(sum(o.order_status = 'DEL'), 0) as count_DEL
from business b
left join orders o on b.id = o.business_id_fk
    and o.date = '2017-03-30'
group by b.id,
    b.business_name;
```

I have assumed the datatype of date column on orders table as date (or atleast formatted string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`).

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/MYRCF76172)

Comment: "count of each order status for every business on 30-03-2017"

Comment: . . I wanted to upvote the answer (despite not being fond of the indentation style ;), but it didn't quite answer the question.

Comment: Thank you @GurV, but for me the list shows the count of businesses from orders table and from business table not all businesses are listing, only one row which is ascending business id with count 0 showing.